# Finding the second linearly independent solution, given the first, using the method of Frobenius

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, power-series, frobenius-method

The given ODE is:

$x(x+1)y''+xy'-y=0$ , with $y_1(x)=x$ and the point of expansion $x=0$

I solved the ODE using reduction of order, which gave me:

$$y(x)= ax + b(x(ln(x+1)-ln(x)) - 1)$$

Knowing what to look out for, I started by putting the ODE into standard form:

$$y''+(1/(x+1))y'-(1/x(x+1) )y=0$$

from which I found that,

$p(x)=(1/(x+1))$ and  $q(x)=-(1/x(x+1))$

I then found the terms $p_o$ and $q_o$ of the indicial equation:

$p_o=   lim_{x→0}⁡〖xp(x)〗=0$ and $q_o=   lim_{x→0}⁡〖x^2 q(x)〗=0$

So my indicial equation was: $r(r-1) = 0$ , which gave me the roots $r=0,1$

From there I checked the condition $r_1-r_2  = 1$ (a positive integer), so my second linearly independent solution had the form:

$$y_2 (x)=cy_1 (x)ln⁡(x)+∑_{n=0}^∞b_n x^{n+1}$$

I plugged this into my original ODE, and after a little series manipulation I got:

$$2cx+c+6b_2 x^3-b_o x+∑_{n=2}^∞x^n [b_{n-1}  (n^2-1)+b_n (n^2+n)]=0$$

I get a recurrence relation of:

$$b_n=-\frac{(n-1)b_{n-1}}{n}$$

And 3 other relations: $c=0$ ,  $2c-b_o=0$ ,  $6b_2=0$

After this part I am unsure how to proceed to the correct answer I found using reduction of order:   $b(x(ln(x+1)-ln(x)) - 1)$

Answer (score 1):

You know one solution $y_1(x)=x$ and the other solution can be easily obtained by assuming $y_2=v(x).y_1(x)$  as its second solution.

Plugging it in the given ODE will reduce it to a second order ODE in dependent variable $v$, which on simplification yields the well known formula

$v(x)=\int $$\frac{e^{-\int P(x).dx}}{y_1^2}dx$. In your case $P(x)=1/(x+1)$ and $y_1(x)=x$.

So, $v(x)=In(1+\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{x}$ gives $y_2=xIn(1+\frac{1}{x})-1$ as the second solution.

**Added**:-If $r_1\ne r_2$ and $r_1-r_2$ is an integer with $r_1>r_2$, then the solution is of the form:

$y=A.y_1+B.y_2$, where $y_1=(y)_{r=r_1}$ and $y_2=\frac{\partial{(r-r_2).y(r)} }{\partial r}|_{r=r_2}$

Comment: I know how to solve this equation using reduction of order, but I want to know how to solve it using the method of frobenius!

Comment: @Riemann...i have added the solution procedure by Frobenius method for your case.